# Is the user with UID 1 "daemon" on all systems?

Tags: users

I'm writing some testing code, and I'd like to know if it will be portable if it assumes that the user with UID 1 is named "daemon" on all Unix systems?

**EDIT**: If not (the answer seems to be no), are there any UID/username mappings that *are* consistent across Unices (other than 0/root, which I'm already using)?

Comment: No, there's nothing you can count on. You can't even really count on the id 0 account being named root - a local admin could change it, though I've never seen it done. Everything else is going to vary among the various distributions. I suggest elaborating on what you are trying to achieve - there might be some way OTHER than knowing what various UIDs are.

Comment: I'm OK with assuming that root is 0 - that's going to be almost universally true. If an admin changes that, they'll know why my tests are failing ;)

Comment: @MichaelKohne - freebsd systems typically have a second root account (with uid=0, gid=0) called `toor` that has `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/csh` as its shell.  gecos name field is `Bourne-again Superuser`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not the case everywhere. On a CentOS 7 system, excerpted from `/etc/passwd`:

```
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin
daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin
```

On Linux, you can use `getent passwd daemon` to find the UID of the `daemon` user, and `getent passwd 1` to find which user has UID 1.

Comment: I agree with this, although a single counter-example would be all it would take to turn this knee-jerk response into a complete answer.

Comment: In response to the suggestion: unfortunately this has to be statically hard-coded, so a dynamic lookup won't help.

Comment: Depending on your circumstances, you might be able to generate a table at compile or install time for the specific system you're on. Other than that, I can't think of anything; there are no guarantees for which UIDs map to which names.

Comment: @joshlf why does it have to be hard-coded?  that sounds like a serious design flaw in whatever it is you're writing.  `getent` and similar tools (or function calls) exist, so it makes sense to use them when you need them.

Comment: It's a test case that's doing string comparison. It's not that I couldn't write it differently - it's just that the testing framework I'm using makes it dead simple to do tests like this, so I'd rather avoid the extra logic if possible.

Answer (score 1):

No.  For Linux, `bin`and `daemon`has swapped places - `bin` used to be #1 and `daemon` #2.  On Minix, the #1/bin actually used to be semi-privileged by the operating system kernel (ie. a bit like #0/root).  On Solaris, UID #1 is called `daemon`, while GID #1 is called `others` - and this is the default group for new users (with the exception of the user made during installation with the `root`-"role", he belongs to the `staff`-group).

UID #0 is of course `root`... GID #0 is usually either `root` or `wheel`.

I think the only *required* user and group is #0.  It's however strongly recommended to have a `bin`and `daemon` group too - to own /*/bin and /*/sbin.  Then you often got a `sys`to own various system-files and directories - especially /dev (in Linux devices are now usually owned by root and lots of different groups for different groups of devices... only /dev/random, /dev/null and /dev/zero are often still got `sys` as group.  On other OS - like Solaris - lot of stuff is owned by `sys:sys`).  Often you got `adm` as owner and group of various logs (originally located at /usr/adm) and sometimes run syslog.  There was often a `man`user/group that owned the man-pages.

`operator` user and/or group was for those permitted to work at The Console - ie. the terminal connected directly to the computer in the locked computer-room.  It often ran back-ups, and thus often a member of the `root`-group to get access to (almost) everything.  `staff` is a group used for "junior-admins", perhaps allowed control over /home and add local users.

Finally we got a series of user:group pairs for various common - and to some degree - required services... some are today uncommon: `lp` = printer, `news` = network-news (NNTP) bulletin board, `mail` = the (local) mail service, `uucp` = Unix to Unix CoPy... a way to pack together stuff like mail and newsgroup-posts, and "copy" it to a remote Unix-machine.  Much used when when people used mostly dial-ups.  `tty` = TeleTYpe... owns various terminals.

Many also had a `games`user.  Games requiring direct access to stuff like sound-cards and video-cards, where run SetUID as this user (games)... and the `game`-user was added to the groups of this hardware.  This way the game got the access it needed to the hardware, without having to be run with full root-access (ie. SetUID=root). It also allowed for shared "Top Score" lists and such between all users on the system.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not necessarily portable.  Any local installation is free to change any UID/name pair (although usually not advised).

For portability, you should always use the operating system's functions to convert to and from numeric/symbolic user and group identifiers (`uid` and `gid`).

If you care about the numeric user id (`uid`) 2, then use commands and system calls which take and return the numeric group ID. Use the `getent` command or similar to convert from numeric to symbolic, when necessary.

If you care about the user `daemon` then use the symbolic string `daemon` when doing user operations, or get the `uid` for the user named `daemon` (again, from `getent` for example) before passing the `uid` to a command or function.

Many commands such as `ls` and `find` contain options for working with both symbolic group names and numeric group identifiers.  Other commands such as `getent` can be used to convert to/from

Comment: Unfortunately the context is that I'm writing tests for code which pretty-prints ACLs, which rely on doing uid -> username lookups, so it's the mapping itself that I care about.

Comment: So for portability you would always want to lookup the `uid` from the ACL to get the symbolic name.  Not a good idea to hardcode `daemon`.  I just noticed my whole answer was about group.  Everything applies I think if you substitute "user" for "group".