# What is the bin user for?

Tags: passwd, non-root-user

As I wrote at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/484626/5132 this is worthy of its own Q&A.

On Linux operating systems …

```
% getent passwd bin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
%
```

… and on FreeBSD …

```
% getent passwd bin
bin:*:3:7:Binaries Commands and Source:/:/usr/sbin/nologin
%
```

… and on OpenBSD …

```
$ getent passwd bin
bin:*:3:7:Binaries Commands and Source:/:/sbin/nologin
$
```

… one can still today find a `bin` account.  But it is pretty much undocumented.  The *Linux Standard Base* version 5 says merely …

> Notes: The `bin` User ID/Group ID is included for compatibility with legacy applications. New applications should no longer use the `bin` User ID/Group ID.

… without explaining the nature of the compatibility mechanism.  [As Joey Hess put it back in 2001](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2001/08/msg00993.html):

> `bin`:**HELP**: No files on my system are owned by user or group `bin`. What good are they? Historically they were probably the owners of binaries in `/bin`? It is not mentioned in the FHS, Debian policy, or the changelog of base-passwd or base-files.

M. Hess's question [remains unanswered in the Debian doco for its base-passwd package to this day](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/base-passwd/blame/master/doc/users-and-groups.sgml#L135), 17 years later.

So what is the `bin` account for?

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244989/ .

Answer (score 38):

## `bin` has not properly been for anything for the entire lifetime of Linux.

Like run-levels and `init` spawning `getty` because of records in `/etc/inittab`, the `bin` account was obsolete in the Unix world before Linux was even invented.  It was an idea from the 1980s that was broken by the invention and adoption of NFS (Network File System) and its `nobody` user.  Its continued presence in user account databases in the late 2010s when people in the commercial Unix world actively discontinued its use in the 1990s is a testament to inertia.

The idea was that the `bin` user owned various directories such as `/bin` and `/usr/bin` (and indeed some of the others mentioned at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/448799/5132 such as `/usr/mbin` and `/usr/5bin`) and the non-set-UID/non-set-GID files within them.  It also owned doco files and directories, such as manual pages.

(In more extreme cases on some Unices it even owned `/` and `/etc`, although the latter was an acknowledged mistake in the creation of a SunOS operating system image.  The former was just dunderheaded.)

Thus the permission to enact software updates, running as user `bin`, was not a blanket permission, running as the superuser, to perform any action whatsoever against the system.  The software upgrader could not read/write private user files, access mailboxes, and so forth; which updating softwares as the superuser of course could.

> Several other special account entries in your `/etc/passwd` file must have passwords.  These are the administrative accounts — `bin`, `daemon`, `sys`, `uucp`, `lp`, and `adm`. […]  The primary reason for the existence of these accounts is the secure ownership of commands, scripts, files, and devices.  And some administrators install passwords for these accounts and actually use them. […]  A password-free `bin` account is extremely useful for a system breaker.

<sup>— Rebecca Thomas and Rik Farrow (1989). *UNIX Administration Guide for System V*.  Prentice Hall. ISBN 9780139428890. p. 452.</sup>

NFS was invented in the early 1980s, and broke this idea completely.

It was already on shaky ground, as the aforegiven quotation alludes.  This was because the ability to update the program image files for basic utilities that the superuser executed as a matter of course, such as `/bin/ls` for example, is a direct vector for gaining superuser privileges, and the division of access in using a `bin` account merely prevented accidentally modifying the wrong directories rather than prevented a malefactor from gaining superuser access.

The advent of NFS highlighted this.  Although NFS had a mechanism for remapping the superuser account to an ordinary non-system user account, it did not have the same for non-root-accounts like `bin`.  So if someone could gain `bin` access on an NFS client it gave them `bin` access to the operating system files on an NFS server.  Indeed, it enabled a superuser on an NFS client, who would otherwise be remapped to an ordinary non-system user on the server, to gain owner access to the server's operating system files and directories.

This was common knowledge by the early 1990s, and at that time received wisdom was to `chown` stuff that was owned by `bin` to being owned by the superuser, to plug this hole that had already become a standard reporting item in Unix security auditing tools and was warned against in the likes of the installation doco for Sendmail.

As far as M. Hess's questions are concerned, this idea was never adopted on Debian, which only came into existence years after it was known to be a bad idea in the Unix world, which indeed knew it to be a bad idea before Linux *itself* was invented.  The BSD operating systems whose history *does* stretch back into the 1980s have long since done away with the actual ownership, but nonetheless retain the user account in the account database.  [FreeBSD converted `bin`:`bin` ownership to `root`:`wheel` ownership back in 1998](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/commit/7faa559f34d8e1b2991d11274edcbe0bf3458336), for example.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015).  [*`/etc/inittab` is a thing of the past.*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/inittab-is-history.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018).  [*run-levels are things of the past.*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/run-levels-are-history.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). *[Don't abuse nobody for running dæmons.](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dont-abuse-nobody-for-daemons.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Thomas Benjamin (1995-11-07). *[Tiger flags *bin* owned system files, disabled accounts](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.sys.hp.hpux/uZFlhqETy5k/Os_mfsFBvxcJ)*.  comp.sys.hp.hpux.
- Bob Proulx (2002-09-15).  *[Re: question about /etc/passwd entries](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/linux.debian.user/r5X2oR5lDws/jbbf9GXI69gJ)*. linux.debian.user.
- Doug Siebert (1999-06-22). *[Re: OS files owned by bin not root](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.security.unix/-gOrlQn5b3c/MNM3UPwTVYoJ)*. comp.security.unix.
- Doug Siebert (1998-06-01). *[Re: AIX : "/" is owned by bin.bin](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/umn.local-lists.security/9SpvFW-bQDU/IIL6qd0ljdwJ)*.  umn.local-lists.security.
- Theo de Raadt (1999-06-22). *[Re: OS files owned by bin not root](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.security.unix/-gOrlQn5b3c/3mpeSQ9ZvGwJ)*. comp.security.unix.
- gene (1994-09-08). *[Why should bin not own a directory](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.security.unix/WVYC8Cl-FGo/discussion)*. comp.security.unix.
- Brad Powell (1993-08-12). *[Re: Root directory 'bin bin'?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.security.unix/_Zh94KzjCfY/mXmnieW7674J)*.  comp.security.unix.
- Mario Wolczko (1991-09-13).  *[Re: What breaks if /etc is not owned by bin?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/alt.security/qQ-Zx6cE1vw/gM1oCUrpAd4J)*. alt.security.

Comment: I have seen files today owned by the `bin` user and group on AIX systems. It’s possible that IBM uses it for a reason. One AIX fileset that comes to mind is `java`. I will have to hop on the AIX systems at work to verify further.

Comment: There are still a substantial number of bin:bin-owned files on an AIX system today.  The [IBM Knowledge Center for AIX 7.2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.security/sysspecaccts.htm), in the Security - Securing the base operating system - Users, groups, and passwords section has the linked page explaining the purpose of the various "System special user accounts", including `bin`.

Comment: From the previous link, `bin` is *not* one of the [common default user IDs that you might be able to remove](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.security/remove_default_usr_accts.htm).  Also: `bin`'s password entry is: `bin:!:2:2::/bin:`

Answer (score -10):

There are 2 case uses that I use bin for 2018. 1: executable's - mainly for web server side .exe files used to complete functions. And 2: logs - sometimes I put my .log or .dat files in my bin folder.

Comment: Are you talking about the `/bin` directory? Or the bin user?

Comment: Are you even on any sort of Unix? You're talking about `.exe` files.

Comment: And why would you put logfiles or configuration files in a "bin" directory?